# chap-links-library customStackOrder() of Links timeline

Tags: javascript, timeline, chap-links-library

I'm using the Chap Links Timeline Library http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc/ and find it very useful. However I need to stack the events in a special order.

I tried to use the customStackOrder() function without any success so far.
How can I access custom data fields in this function?

My data elements look like:

```
data.push({
  start: new Date( msg.timestamp ),  
  content: msg.text,
  stackOrder: msg.level
});
```

and

```
function customStackOrder(A,B) {
  return A.stackOrder - B.stackOrder
}
```

But A.stackOrder and B.stackOrder is undefined.

Comment: Please add relevant code to show what you tried. Also add any errors you encountered. This will help people to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply -> updated

Comment: Unforutnately I have never worked with timeline, so I won't be able to provide a thorough answer. I did find however an example of an implemented custom stackOrder function: https://github.com/almende/chap-links-library/issues/121 (last comment). Hopefully that will help you a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access custom data fields in this function?

The Timeline does just ignores custom fields, and there is no easy way to access them. Usable item properties in the function `customStackOrder` are the actual position and size (`left`, `right`, `width`, `height`) and timestamps (`start` and optionally `end`).

If you *really* want to do this, you will have to apply an inefficient hack. This is not officially supported and I don't recommend it:

- From the items passed to the sorting function you will have to determine their table index: `var indexA = mytimeline.items.indexOf(itemA)`
- Read the data of this item from your original data table: `var dataA = data[indexA]`.
- Read your custom field from this: `var stackOrderA = dataA.stackOrder`

Edit:

Another trick could be: if you don't use the field `className`, you could misuse this to hold the value of your `stackOrder` field. Just ensure the values cannot collide with some actual css.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think the hack with the className is the most appropriate solution for me, even if it's still a hack.